# Is it possible to redirect https to http using dns?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, https

I asked this on SO, but this might be a better forum?

I just switched a domain from a custom site to a shopify site. The custom site used SSL, and any customer who has gone to the site in Chrome most likely has https saved in their history.

Since the user attempts to access one url, but the site is actually coming from shopify's servers, Chrome throws the big red error warning the user that the site is probably not the site they meant to access.

Is there any way, using DNS, to redirect all https attempts to http? Or another solution to prevent this error?

Comment: To those downvoting, help me be a better member of this community by explaining why?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I imagine the downvotes are due to the "does not show any research effort" clause, which you can see if you hover over the downvote button. The base functionality of DNS is fairly straightforward, and it's likely you could have discovered the answer to this question on your own with just a bit of research.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, for this use case, DNS has no functionality other than to map names to IP addresses. There is no way to redirect https to http via DNS.

You should contact Shopify support to see if they are able to provide SSL support for your site.

Comment: For better or worse, given the fact that many dns providers support domain forwarding/url redirection (they terminate the connection on their own web server and issue a 3xx [which they fake an A record for in DNS]) in their dns control panels, I can understand why people think dns has redirect functionality.

Answer (score 0):

See if your provider offers **hosted SSL**. In that way they will get a cert from you, and when you redirect a.com to b.net, you will get a reply from b.net, but with a cert that matches the calling domain (a.com).
I'm currently doing this with Zendesk

Answer (score -1):

DNS is not meant for that purpose but if you are looking for the same level of latency, it's achievable using Cloudflare. Just add an 'SSL Off' page rule.

Here's what turning off SSL does: *"No secure connection between your visitor and Cloudflare, and no secure connection between Cloudflare and your web server either. This means that visitors can only view your website over HTTP, and any visitor attempting to connect via HTTPS will receive a HTTP 301 Redirect to the plain HTTP version of your website."*

Source:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-Off-Flexible-SSL-Full-SSL-Full-SSL-Strict-SSL-Only-mean-

Update: Though this is an HTTP 301 redirect, it's still pretty fast. Here is the proof:

I am using a Cloudflare page rule to redirect `www` to `non-www` on my website. First, it resolves my domain and then it does an HTTP 301 to a `non-www` domain. In the image below, you can see the pink regions (DNS time) are almost exactly the same in both IP resolution and HTTP 301 redirect.

[Screen of the Pingdom Tool test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs4QP.png)

Comment: "HTTP 301 Redirect" - so not a redirect via DNS like the question asked for, then?

Comment: The only reason I suppose the user asked for DNS redirection was latency that would have otherwise crept in due to meta redirect. This inbuilt Cloudflare feature offers the same level of latency as that of regular DNS name resolution. So it serves the purpose. I think this is the best answer to kind of question the asker asked. No need to downvote.